# Android OnClickListener for RecyclerView's Child's Child

Tags: android

What I want to do is set an onClickListener for an ImageView that is in an item in a recyclerview. I only want a click on that ImageView to do CODE A and click anywhere else to run CODE B. How can I do that? I am using:

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    ClickListener clickListener;

    List<PostContent> posts = Collections.emptyList();

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setPosts(List<PostContent> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_row, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(posts.get(i).name);
        viewHolder.username.setText("@" + posts.get(i).username);
        viewHolder.time_post.setText(posts.get(i).time_post);
        viewHolder.content.setText(posts.get(i).content);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        public void ItemClicked(View view, int pos);
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView name;
        TextView username;
        TextView time_post;
        TextView content;
        ImageView profile;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            time_post = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.ItemClicked(v, getPosition());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

for my adapter and view holder.

Comment: Post your Adapter too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so this might not be the correct way to do it, but this is how I got it to work.

Firstly create a click interface in your ViewHolder:

```
private TaskListRecyclerviewClickInterface clickListener;
```

...

```
this.clickListener = clickListener;
```

...

```
public interface TaskListRecyclerviewClickInterface {
    public void onItemClicked(int position, String tag);
}
```

Then add an onclicklistener to the views you want and call this interface when these items are clicked like so:

```
holder_view.setTag("holder");
holder_view.setOnClickListener(this);
imageView.setTag("ImageView");
imageView.setOnclickListener(this);
```

And the onClickListener :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (clickListener != null) {
        clickListener.onItemClicked(getPosition(), v.getTag().toString());
    }
}
```

Now from your activity, pass this Interface to your Adapter in the constructor and then pass the interface to this viewholder like so:

```
public InboxTaskListAdapter(List<Items> items, InboxTasksViewHolder.TaskListRecyclerviewClickInterface clickListener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }
```

In onCreateViewHolder you should pass the interface to the viewholder.

Now in your Activity or fragment just implement this listener and override the onItemClicked method. You will now get the view position and tag that was clicked on.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works like a charm. I had pretty much the same thing but I was setting the clickListener for either holder or imageview, never both at the same time. Got it to work. Big thank you.