# RecyclerView setting onclick event at onCreateViewHolder, not onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I'm pretty new to Android and is faced with a problem here.

I have recently switched to using recycler view instead of listview in one of my activities named `activity_drinks_menu` for displaying menus of drinks.

What is supposed to be happening is this:

I click on one of the items (holder.layout is clicked), it should "expand" to show more options related to it. I could press on one of the options in these list of options. When I do so, a popup window (activityforresult) appears and the option that I newly chose gets reflected to my `Drinks` object. The options list is still "expanded" in case I want to edit more options for that specific item.

Everything works fine until I see the popup window (activityforresult), get the result back from the activity, reflect it to the `Drinks` object. After this `Drinks` object has been updated, as I have mentioned above, the options list MUST still be "expanded", showing all the options available for me to tweek with. However, it gets "closed".

I am guessing this is because of the way how my code is written but could not figure out a brilliant way to resolve this problem. Here's my code:

```
package com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Customized adapter for RecyclerView
 */

public class DrinkMenuItem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrinkMenuItem.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ViewGroup parent;
    private ArrayList<Drink> menu;
    private ArrayList<DrinkSelected> selected;
    private DrinkMenuBasketItem selectedAdapter;

    private DrinkMenuDropdownItem dropdownAdapter;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout layout;
        public TextView name, price;
        public ListView dropdown;
        public Button basket;
        public boolean tabbed = false;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_layout);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_name);
            price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_price);
            dropdown = (ListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_dropdown_list);
            basket = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drink_menu_basket_button);
        }
    }

    public DrinkMenuItem(Context context, ArrayList<Drink> menu, ArrayList<DrinkSelected> selected, DrinkMenuBasketItem selectedAdapter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menu = menu;
        this.selected = selected;
        this.selectedAdapter = selectedAdapter;
        this.dropdownAdapter = null;
    }

    public void updateDropdown(int requestedOption, int responsedOptionitem) {
        dropdownAdapter.updateSelectedOption(requestedOption, responsedOptionitem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.parent = parent;
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_drink_menu, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Drink d = menu.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(d.getName());
        holder.price.setText(d.getPrice() + d.totalAdditionalPrice() + "원");

        setOnClickEvent(holder, position, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menu.size();
    }

    private void setOnClickEvent(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, final ViewGroup parent) {
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!holder.tabbed) {
                    //make dropdown
                    dropdownAdapter = new DrinkMenuDropdownItem(context, menu, position, holder.price);
                    holder.dropdown.setAdapter(dropdownAdapter);
                    setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);

                    //set dropdown-related stuff
                    holder.tabbed = true;
                    holder.basket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   ((RecyclerView) parent).smoothScrollToPosition(position);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("dropdown", "is this being called when options is changed? 1");
                //delete dropdown
                holder.dropdown.setAdapter(null);
                menu.get(position).returnToUnselected();
                holder.price.setText(menu.get(position).getPrice() + "원");
                setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);

                //reset dropdown-related stuff
                holder.tabbed = false;
                holder.basket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.basket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drink d = menu.get(position);
            boolean doesExist = false; int i = 0;

            //checking if already in the list
            for(DrinkSelected ds : selected) {
                //the same entry if the name and option are the same
                if(ds.getName().equals(d.getName()) && ds.getOption().equals(d.printOptionForSelected())) {
                    doesExist = true;
                    i = selected.indexOf(ds);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(doesExist) {
                selected.get(i).setCount(selected.get(i).getCount()+d.getCount());
                selected.get(i).setPrice(selected.get(i).getPrice()+(d.getPrice()+d.totalAdditionalPrice()));
            }
            else {
                    selected.add(new DrinkSelected(d.getName(), d.getCount(), d.getPrice() + d.totalAdditionalPrice(), d.printOptionForSelected()));
                }

                selectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                holder.dropdown.setAdapter(null);
                menu.get(position).returnToUnselected();
                holder.price.setText(menu.get(position).getPrice() + "원");

                setListViewHeight(holder.dropdown);

                //set basket button gone
                holder.basket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setListViewHeight(final ListView l) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = l.getLayoutParams();

        if(l.getAdapter() == null) {
            params.height = 0;
        }
        else {
            int numberOfItems = l.getAdapter().getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                View item = l.getAdapter().getView(itemPos, null, l);
                item.measure(0, 0);
                totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = l.getDividerHeight() * (numberOfItems - 1);    

            // Set list height.
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        }

        l.setLayoutParams(params);

        l.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

As the code shows, I need to have the information about the position of the item in order to display the correct options in my dropdown list. Therefore, I cannot `setOnClickEvents` in my onCreateViewHolder method, because there is no way for me to know which position it is for.

But then because I am "resetting" my onClickEvents every time the ViewHolder object gets binded to the itemView, I think this error is occurring. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: implement onclick listener in onBindViewHolder

Comment: How about this method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174712/android-onclicklistener-for-recyclerviews-childs-child/31176508#31176508

Comment: call `setOnClickListener` in your `onCreateViewHolder` and use `ViewHolder#get*Position` in the listener

Comment: @Mina Fawzy I am trying not to do so because I think that's where it's causing all my troubles right now, because to me, it seems that onBindViewHolder is "rebinding" my items upon resuming the activity after the startActivityForResult is finished thereby resetting the onclicklistener, defaulting back to "closed" dropdown.

Comment: @Smashing I've looked into the link you provided but it seems like that it's still a method to implement during my onBindViewHolder as I see that `.setTag`.... Thx tho!

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry but I'm really really new to android and don't quite get what it means by `ViewHolder#get*Position` that you told me... could you maybe elaborate more or give me some examples of what that means? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is the custom class I use to enable onclick from

in your activity

```
RecyclerView drawerList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.DrawerList);
drawerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); 

// pass context , implement click listener interface
    drawerList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecycleOntouchListener(Home.this, new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void OnClick(View view, int position) {
                    SelectItem(position);
                }
            }));
```

custom class to handle on touch

```
public class RecycleOntouchListner implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private ClickListener mClickListner;

        public RecycleOntouchListner(Context mContext,  ClickListener clickListner) {

            this.mClickListner = clickListner;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mClickListner != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                mClickListner.OnClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                return false;

            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }
```

interface to handle click

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void OnClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Comment: So in your program that `SelectItem(position)` method accesses the item and takes appropriate actions with it? I'm really sorry but I don't quite get how I should apply this customized `onClick` event in my adapter. So instead of passing position as the parameter to my `setOnClickEvents`, I can use this customized `ClickListtener` to get position of my item? If so, how do I get the position...? I'm sorry I'm very very new to Android and have not had any chance to go through proper deep-down studies with it and am very vaugely understanding touch events and onclick events :S