# Short click not working in Recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which includes a checkbox. I had implemented click listener to that checkbox . But my current issue is checkbox is working only when I do a long press.
here my code is.

My Recyclerview item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PROJECT_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:background="@drawable/mirlogo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/labelsale"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/PROJECT_fav"
        android:layout_width="30sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter

```
public class HomeDataManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeDataManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mProjectName;
        ImageView mImage;
        CheckBox mCheck;


        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
            mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_image);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array

        final HomeProjects projects = HomeProjects.PROJECTS[i];
        // Set the values
        viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projects.get(HomeProjects.Field.NAME));
        viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(projects.geti(HomeProjects.Field.IMAGE));
        viewHolder.mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Item Favorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return HomeProjects.PROJECTS.length;
    }


}
```

Comment: Tried your code (removing the view ProjectName not included in your xml) and the checkbox worked well on the onClick. Can you provide more info ?

Comment: projectname is needed . i just removed it from code for posting here because i have problem with the checkbox click only.  checkbox is working correctly . but my problem is i should do a long press on that checkbox to work. otherwise it will go to next activity which is already defined(I didnt included it in here).

Comment: Sorry for not understand your needs. Your checkbox only works when you do a long click on it, and when you simple click on it it takes you to another activity (maybe you set another onClickListener that is receiving the event), or you just want your checkbox to be triggered when you do a long click?

Comment: i only need simple click on my checkbox. but its not working.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31176508/4448700

Comment: thanks i will give feedback after trying that method.

Comment: @Smashing : its not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your custom RecyclerClickListener and implement setOnCheckedChangeListener for checkbox in the constructor of RecyclerViewHolder.

```
itemView.mCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(){
//Implement your code here}});
```

For handling RecyclerlayoutClicks:
This code should be used in  the constructor of RecyclerViewHolder class.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
//Your Code}});
```